# 2-day difference: why select convert(datetime, 43279) = '2018-06-30' and DateTime.FromOADate(43279) = '2018-06-28'?

Tags: c++, sql, .net, datetime, ole

I have some legacy C++ app that uses ADO and some other COM&OLE technologies.

While debugging i found strange thing: some part of my program has a variable of COleDateTime (C++ class), that stores, e. g., 43279 value, displays it on screen and saves to SQL database.

Since in debug mode i cannot ad-hoc convert float to readable datetime, i used SQL server and found strange thing:

`select convert(datetime, 43279)` produces '2018-06-30'

I googled a little and found .NET method

`DateTime.FromOADate(43279)` that produces '2018-06-28' which is correct and expected

So, this is so unobvious! and why 2-days difference of float representation of datetime exists between OLE and SQL?

Comment: I don't think that the c++ tag is appropriate here.

Comment: @skaef, because FromOADate zero is 30 December 1899 (  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx ),  while sql datetime has zero on 1900-01-01 00:00:00
2 days difference :-)